# After I call an array returned from function, it give me "undefined"

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-fql

I call the facebook fql to get all members of a group. If i check allmembers in the first function, it works just fine, but when i call it in the second one, in returns "undefined".

```
function getAllMembers(groupid){
              var allmembers = new Array();
              var content = document.getElementById('content-text');
              FB.api({
                method: 'fql.query',
                query: 'select uid from group_member where gid =' + groupid
              },
              function(resp){
                for (var i=0, l= resp.length; i<l; i++)
                {
                 allmembers[i] = resp[i].uid;
                }
                return allmembers;
              }
              )    
    }

    function retrieveMessages(groupid){
        var allmembers;
        allmembers = getAllMembers(groupid);
        console.log(allmembers);     
    }
```

I don't understand where's the mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `getAllMembers()` is making a asynchronous function call using `FB` API, which means that the `getAllMembers()` returns before the FB call is completed.

You need to use a callback function, to solve this problem as given below

```
function getAllMembers(groupid, callback){
    var content = document.getElementById('content-text');
    FB.api({
        method: 'fql.query',
        query: 'select uid from group_member where gid =' + groupid
    },  function(resp){
        var allmembers = new Array();
        for (var i=0, l= resp.length; i<l; i++)
        {
            allmembers.push( resp[i].uid);
        }
        callback(allmembers)
    })    
}

function retrieveMessages(groupid){
    getAllMembers(groupid, function(allmembers){
        console.log(allmembers);     
    });
}
```

Comment: @StefanPerju sorry updated, `allmembers` has to be the callback parameter

Comment: Ok, so next i'll do every operation with the allmembers variable in the new function...

Answer (score 0):

At a guess the call is asynchronous - which means that `getAllMembers` returns before your success function (`function(resp){}`) executes...

Try moving the `console.log` inside your `function(resp)`...

```
var allmembers = new Array();

function getAllMembers(groupid){
          var allmembers = new Array();
          var content = document.getElementById('content-text');
          FB.api({
            method: 'fql.query',
            query: 'select uid from group_member where gid =' + groupid
          },
          function(resp){
            for (var i=0, l= resp.length; i<l; i++)
            {
             allmembers[i] = resp[i].uid;
            }
            console.log(allmembers);     
          }
          );    
}

function retrieveMessages(groupid){
    getAllMembers(groupid);
}
```

Comment: I need to save all members, in an array, in the retrieveMessages function. That's why i use it.

Comment: That's fine but you need to understand that the call to the api isn't instant - so you need to create the array when you get the response and then carry on working. instead of logging `allmembers` as I show above, you could call another function to do the rest of your processing - but there's a delay between calling the API and between it responding (possibly several seconds) so the rest of your processingf must happen after you get the response.